# How to allow only 1 attachment for each post and make it a requirement for each post?

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I am currently attempting to configure the settings of attachments to make it required and only one attachment attached to a post but all my changes did not have any good results.

I have looked into adding an action to attachment_register function and some documentation about attachments in Wordpress but still no positive results.

Comment: You should post the code you tried, and explain why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with the ACF ([Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)) plugin to accomplish this.

You can use the plugin add a new required media upload (picture/file) meta field for posts.

In the settings for this new Custom Field group, you also use the plugin to remove the default "featured image" field from the edit post screen, to force the user to use your new required media upload function.

All that said, you will probably need to make adjustments to your theme template files to use the ACF functions to display the data on your site. This will probably be pretty straight forward as long as you have ability to alter you theme template files.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mike C's answer in regards to using ACF ([Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)) with a step by step walkthrough of how to achieve such a thing.

1. Install the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin
2. Once Activated you will see a new section in the Wordpress Left Menu
3. Click Custom Fields
4. First we need a field group, click Add New
5. Name this something relevant such as "Page Attachment"
6. Now Click Add Field and Fill out the fields, example below:

   - Field Label: Upload Attachment
   - Field Name: page_attachment
   - Field Type: File
   - Return Value: If you want someone to click a link to download, select File URL
7. Scroll Down To The Section Titled Locations

   - You mentioned that this should be on posts so I would recommend the below selections:
   - Post Type -> Is Equal To -> Post
8. Click Save/Update
9. Go To A Post, you will now see a button that reads Add File, you cannot update/create a post without having a file attached.
10. This is the admin work completed now we need to make the file appear in the post.

Now if you want the file to appear at the end of the post, under the header or even in the sidebar that is fine. Simply add the following code:

```
<p><a href="<?php the_field('page_attachment');?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
Download Attachment
</a></p>
```

Obviously this is just a link that it echos, so this could be added to an image to make it seem a little more stylish, it's up to you. But this is the simple way of adding a file.

Now if you wanted to add this into the page content midway, you would either need to make a shortcode function to display it. Or you could add something like:

```
<a href="#attachment" title="Download Attachment">Download Now</a>
```

And then add the following to the bottom of your post:

```
<p id="attachment"><a href="<?php the_field('page_attachment');?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">
Download Attachment
</a></p>
```

This means, whenever some clicks on the link that takes them to #attachment, it will jump them down to the bottom of the post where the download link is.

Any questions, let me know.

Comment: Nice step by step!